# DataTables : Using Row grouping, how do I get a count of grouped entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables to create a grouped by data grid. I was able to group my table.

I want to accomplish getting the total count of entries as the grouped row count and not as the total entries count, how would I go about doing that?

[image]

The highlighted part as in the above image should show "Showing 1 to 8 of 8 entries" since there are 8 groups.

Please refer my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hh4kq5y0/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bJQueryUI": true
        }).rowGrouping({
            bExpandableGrouping: true,
            bExpandSingleGroup: false,
            iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
            asExpandedGroups: [""]
        });

        GridRowCount();
    });

    function GridRowCount() {
        $('span.rowCount-grid').remove();
        $('input.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').remove();

        $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('[id|=group-id]').each(function () {
            var rowCount = $(this).nextUntil('[id|=group-id]').length;
            $(this).find('td').append($('<span />', { 'class': 'rowCount-grid' }).append($('<b />', { 'text': rowCount })));
        });

        $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter').append($('<input />', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'expandedOrCollapsedGroup collapsed', 'value': 'Expanded All Group' }));

        $('.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').live('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').val('Collapse All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').val('Expanded All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.expanded-group').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DataTables sets this *Show x to y from z* text by default to

```
"sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries"
```

and looking in the source code, the three placeholder just get replaced by internal variables. You may be able to alter them, but I don't know for sure and wouldn't suggest doing it doing it anyway.

If you want to change that info display, you could use some jQuery in your `GridRowCount` function, where you can access the total number of grouping rows via

```
$('.dataTables_wrapper').find('[id|=group-id]').length
```

Hope that helps.